# How to total CSV column?

Tags: python, csv

I want to total a column in a CSV file using the python script below.  However, I'm getting the following error.

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7.3'
```

What is wrong with my script?

```
import csv

cr = csv.reader(open("companylist.csv","rb"))
cr.next() # to skip the header 

total = 0
for row in cr:  
   total += int(row[2])
   # possibly do other things with data/rows 

print total
```

Comment: Um... `int` doesn't have a decimal point, so the error message is entirely accurate (and clear): **invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7.3'**. You can't cast a floating point value (a number with a decimal point) to an int (which doesn't accept a decimal point).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating the total variable and incrementing it, you can do it in one shot via a [Generator Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension).

```
import csv

with open("book1.csv", "rb") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    total = sum(float(row["column_name_here"]) for row in reader)
print(total)
```

Comment: Pretty good answer except you forgot to make put the list comp inside a `with open("companylist.csv", "rb") as cr:`...

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting "ValueError: could not convert string to float: n/a"

Comment: @josh  what are the possible values/data types in row[2]? If you have strings are you just trying to count the rows in the file or sum the values of the column?

Comment: @py_noob: That's not what I meant...in fact it's not even valid syntax.

Comment: @josh , sorry, after some research i realized that the headers were causing the issue you mentioned above regarding the string conversion.  I updated my code above.  Just change the column header to the correct string value.

Comment: @martineau , sorry, I had wrote it in an editor and didnt compile it so i missed the error.  Anyway, it's updated again and I tested it this time.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying converting non-integer string value to int with your statement

```
total += int(row[2]) # possibly do other things with data/rows
```

use `float()` instead of it:

```
total += float(row[2]) # possibly do other things with data/rows
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, cast to `float` instead of `int`.

```
import csv

cr = csv.reader(open("companylist.csv","rb"))
cr.next() # to skip the header 

numbers = (float(row[2]) for row in cr)
total = sum(numbers)

print total
```